# How to write two case statements with in case

Tags: sql-server

My query shows errors, could any one please help me.

My Query:

```
SELECT     A.EmpCodeC, 
           E.EmpNameC, 
           B.DesigNameC, 
           C.DeptNameC, 
           D.SecNameC, 
           A.ClockDateD, 
           TimeClk1N, 
           TimeClk2N, 
           TimeClk3N, 
           TimeClk4N, 
           A.BJClk1N, 
           A.BJClk2N, 
           A.BJClk3N, 
           A.BJClk4N, 
           A.TimeInN, 
           A.TimeOutN, 
           A.ShiftCodeC, 
           A.NormalN, 
           A.ActlWrkHrsN, 
           A.LatenessN, 
           A.UnderN, 
           A.OT10N, 
           A.OT15N, 
           A.OT20N, 
           A.OT30N, 
           A.SflatN, 
           A.ShiftAllN, 
           A.MealAllN, 
           A.TranAllN, 
           A.Oth1AllN, 
           A.Oth2AllN, 
           A.HealthAllN, 
           A.AttdAllN, 
           A.ReaCodeC, 
           A.SplReaCodeC, 
           Isnull(I.PayTypeC, '') PayType, 
           E.BasicSalaryN, 
           CASE 
                      WHEN Datename(dw, A.ClockDateD)='Sunday' THEN 
                                 CASE 
                                            WHEN A.OT20N >4 THEN ((E.BasicSalaryN/(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2))/9)* (4+A.OT10N+A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
                                            ELSE ((E.BasicSalaryN                /(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2) )/9)* (A.OT10N+A.OT15N+ A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
                                 END AS OT_Amnt, 
                                 CASE 
                                            WHEN A.OT20N >4 THEN ((E.BasicSalaryN/(SubString(CAST(EOMONTH ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2))/9)* (A.OT15N-4)) 
                                            ELSE ('0.00') 
                                 END AS Insentive_Amnt 
                      ELSE '0.00' OT_Amnt '0.00' Insentive_Amnt 
           END 
FROM       Daily A 
INNER JOIN TMSStrt.DBO.Designation B 
ON         A.DesigCodeC = B.DesigCodeC 
INNER JOIN TMSStrt.DBO.Department C 
ON         A.DeptCodeC = C.DeptCodeC 
INNER JOIN TMSStrt.DBO.Section D 
ON         A.SecCodeC = D.SecCodeC 
AND        D.DeptCodeC = C.DeptCodeC 
INNER JOIN StaffMaster E 
ON         A.EmpCodeC = E.EmpCodeC 
LEFT JOIN  TMSStrt.DBO.Reason I 
ON         A.ReaCodeC = I.ReasonCodeC 
WHERE      A.ClockDateD >= '01-07-2016' 
AND        A.ClockDateD <= '04-07-2016' 
ORDER BY   E.EmpNameC, 
           A.ClockDateD
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  One line of code per visible width, and indent by 4 spaces to make the text monospaced.

Comment: Posting a large amount of text and saying it "shows errors" without saying what those errors are, what line they occur on, and more importantly what you are actually trying to achieve is unlikely to solicit a positive response. As already requested format your code, identify the specific section that is causing an error, describe what you are trying to do, and then someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer CASE is wrong. Yo cannot return two columns from inside the CASE, you can only return a single value. So instead you could write:

```
       ...
       CASE 
           WHEN Datename(dw, A.ClockDateD)='Sunday' THEN 
               CASE 
                   WHEN A.OT20N >4 THEN ((E.BasicSalaryN/(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2))/9)* (4+A.OT10N+A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
                   ELSE ((E.BasicSalaryN                /(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2) )/9)* (A.OT10N+A.OT15N+ A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
               END 
           ELSE 0.0 
       END AS OT_Amnt,
       CASE 
           WHEN Datename(dw, A.ClockDateD)='Sunday' AND A.OT20N >4 THEN ((E.BasicSalaryN/(SubString(CAST(EOMONTH ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2))/9)* (A.OT15N-4)) 
           ELSE 0.0
       END AS Insentive_Amnt,
       ...
```

Also be careful with those date to varchar CASTs, SUBSTRINGs and mixing numeric and sting data in arithmetic. It would be better to use date functions (eg: `Year(EOMONTH ( A.ClockDateD ))-2000` instead of `(SubString(CAST(EOMONTH ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2)`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking at what you have so far - there is a fair bit wrong with your query.
First of all the case statements which you have nested (This won't work by the way) have the exact same behavior? What I think they should be is as follows

**Case Statements:**

```
      CASE 
        WHEN Datename(dw, A.ClockDateD)='Sunday' AND A.OT20N >4 
        THEN ((E.BasicSalaryN/(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2))/9)* (4+A.OT10N+A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
        ELSE ((E.BasicSalaryN/(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2) )/9)* (A.OT10N+A.OT15N+ A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
      END AS OT_Amnt


     CASE 
       WHEN Datename(dw, A.ClockDateD)='Sunday' WHEN A.OT20N >4 
       THEN ((E.BasicSalaryN/(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2))/9)* (4+A.OT10N+A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
       ELSE ((E.BasicSalaryN/(Substring(Cast(Eomonth ( A.ClockDateD ) AS VARCHAR(20)),9,2) )/9)* (A.OT10N+A.OT15N+ A.OT20N+ A.OT30N))
     END AS Insentive_Amnt,
```

The nesting is removed completely and just call two separate case statements, with MSSQL there is **negligible overhead in duplicating a case statement**.

If you want to keep your nesting idea you will need to change over to a stored procedure. In there you can set a variable using if statements and then call your case statements in the if statement.

From what I see though you don't need a stored procedure. Another note

```
ELSE '0.00' OT_Amnt '0.00' Insentive_Amnt
```

I don't know what this is, but it will **never work**, if you are trying to concatenate something you need to use the & or  + syntax depending on datatype.

Comment: Both CASE expressions return the wrong result if datename is not Sunday, it should be 0. The 2nd CASE should also return 0 if `A.OT20N <= 4`. I also thought of removing the nesting, but I would have to repeat the test for datename being Sunday, and I am not sure which one actually performs best (it will depend on data)

Comment: If that is the case, I would say use a stored procedure with a IF statement block in there.

Comment: How would a stored procedure help in this case? This is a single query, you can't call a stored procedure from within a query. Are you perhaps thinking of table valued function and CROSS APPLY? I think the best approach is the CASE expression (nested or flattened out)

Comment: I wouldn't use a stored procedure in the statement. I would convert the entire query to a statement and then return the entire dataset with that stored procedure. You don't have much choice if you want to do nested calls like you are doing. You have two options, two separate Case statements or Stored procedure with a IF statement

Comment: I still cannot see how a stored procedure would help. The IF condition has to be applied once for every row in the query. Either you have to run 2 identical queries, put the condition in WHERE and union the results or use the 2 CASE expressions with identical conditions. An IF works on a single values (i.e. a single record). Could you, please,  provide an example of how you would use an IF in a stored procedure to achieve the desired result?