# How to write two case statements with in the single case in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have tried a lot. But its showing the error. Any 1 please help me.

***My Query*** (Please see in Image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRl1h.png)

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question instead of an image. Also, be more specific about _what_ error you get. Looking at your code it's not clear what the desired output should be from the case expressions, please clarify that too.

Comment: Please copy the SQL statement here. It's easier for us to edit your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write two case statements with in case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197852/how-to-write-two-case-statements-with-in-case)

Comment: If you want a better response, you should edit and improve your existing question, not just repost the same question but with an image instead of text for your query. If the two answers on your first question don't help you, then maybe you should give some feedback to the people that answered as to why, then they might be able to adjust their answer to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest case statements, each one needs to stand alone. And you cannot give them different names.

You can try to trick with Coalesce, like

```
SELECT COALESCE
  (
    CASE WHEN condition1 THEN calculation1 ELSE calcelse1 END,
    CASE WHEN condition2 THEN calculation2 ELSE calcelse2 END,
    etc...
  )
```

but I think it wont solve your problem directly.

IMHO you need to enhanced each of your case statements. Or you are going to implement this with a pivot statement. And on first sight, you need to think about redesigning your data model ...